# Does all apps have their code inside "com" folder?

Tags: reverse-engineering, android, android-debug, android-applicationinfo

I have a very basic question with respect to app development. I have no experience in app development, but, I need to reverse engineer android apps. When I reverse engineer (decompile using apktool or androguard) apps, I am seeing that every app has a package (folder structure) that begins with "**com**". Does every app have this **com** folder (I guess eclipse creates this folder, inside which the developers code). **Is this assumption valid for all apps?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not. You can choose what to use as namespace. Many developers uses "com" for commercial applications and "org" for free ones but it's entirely up to you.

Comment: Okay, got it, thanks! I wish to ask one more important thing here. **Is there a set of keywords** (like com, org, in etc.) within which the root of an app's package structure will begin with?

Comment: @AnnamalaiN see my answer below. Generally, any string could be root of package structure. There are conventions, but no way to force it...

Comment: Namespaces are mainly designed for disambiguation of classes. Theorically you can name two classes with the same name but in different namespaces. Subclassing is a typical example but you can use them as you want: root is usually "com", "org" or "net" but they can be whatever you choose.

Answer (score 2):

No its not necessary to have `com` folder.

The com folder is because of package name.

If you take any package, lets say - `com.sudosaints.android`

So in this case src code directory structure will be - src -> com -> sudosaints -> android.

In case of `in.sudosaints.android`, directory structure will be - src->in->sudosaints->android

So assumption of `com` folder is not valid for all apps.

Comment: Okay, got it, thanks! I wish to ask one more important thing here. Is there a set of keywords (like com, org, in etc.) within which the root of an app's package structure will begin with?

Comment: Not sure bt you can try 'src' folder

Comment: When I decompile the code, I do not see a "src" folder. I use baksmali (from apk tool). Is there any other decompilation tool that gives the folder structure?

Comment: No there is no such set of keywords you can search for

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure whether or not this can be overridden, but it is based on the package name of the application. The recommended way, which as far as I have seen, all developers do follow create a package called `com.yourcompany.yourappname`.

In this example the source code would be found in:
`com.yourcompany.yourappname/src`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

General convention for naming packages is based on domain owned by author of the program.

For example, if your company has webpage

> www.mycompany.com

their programs will generaly have package structure starting with

```
com.mycompany.nameofproject
```

So thats why most packages start with `com`, because most companies have webpage ending with `.com`.